# Substrate error in both nightly & stable versions

Tags: substrate

I use rust stable 1.55.0, run `cargo build --release` then having the below error in partity-db crate

```
 error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> C:\Users\USER\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\parity-db-0.3.1\src\index.rs:502:3
    |
501 |     fn madvise_random(&self, _map: &mut memmap2::MmapMut) {
    |                                                           - expected `()` because of default return type
502 |         Ok(())
    |         ^^^^^^- help: consider using a semicolon here: `;`
    |         |
    |         expected `()`, found enum `std::result::Result`
    |
    = note: expected unit type `()`
                    found enum `std::result::Result<(), _>`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.
error: could not compile `parity-db` due to previous error
```

When I switch to rust version 1.57.0-nightly, having another error in prost-derive crate

```
error[E0034]: multiple applicable items in scope
   --> C:\Users\USER\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\prost-derive-0.7.0\src\lib.rs:109:14
    |
109 |             .intersperse(quote!(|));
    |              ^^^^^^^^^^^ multiple intersperse found
    |
    = note: candidate #1 is defined in an impl of the trait Iterator for the type Map<I, F>
    = note: candidate #2 is defined in an impl of the trait Itertools for the type T
help: disambiguate the associated function for candidate #1
    |
105 ~         let tags = Iterator::intersperse(field
106 +             .tags()
107 +             .into_iter()
108 +             .map(|tag| quote!(#tag)), {
109 +         let mut _s = $crate::__private::TokenStream::new();
110 +         $crate::quote_each_token!(_s $($tt)*);
  ...
help: disambiguate the associated function for candidate #2
    |
105 ~         let tags = Itertools::intersperse(field
106 +             .tags()
107 +             .into_iter()
108 +             .map(|tag| quote!(#tag)), {
109 +         let mut _s = $crate::__private::TokenStream::new();
110 +         $crate::quote_each_token!(_s $($tt)*);
  ...

For more information about this error, try rustc --explain E0034.
error: could not compile prost-derive due to previous error
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: build failed
```

How can I fix this? Thank you!

Comment: I see the source code of parity-db-0.3.1
Maybe caused the method is not implemented for Window

Comment: `#[cfg(not(unix))]
 fn madvise_random(&self, _map: &mut memmap2::MmapMut) {
  Ok(())
 }`

Comment: also ran into this before. I deleted the ok(()) of line#502 to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem exclusively found on windows. If you delete the OK(()) on line #502 the error should be solved.